# Setting a CMS Page Name in Magento for Google Analytics

Tags: magento

In /app/code/core/Mage/GoogleAnalytics/Block/Ga.php line 88 makes reference to 
$this->getPageName() which is used in line 95 of the same script. While this makes sense in that if the page has a "Page Name" defined it will attach it to the Google Analytics code what I can not find is where in the Magento Admin or the page XML do I set this "Page Name" for a CMS page? In the notes on Ga.php it says "The custom "page name" may be set from layout or somewhere else. It must start from slash." but I don't see how I would do that.

When I asked this question to Magento Support they came back with "Look at our design guide" and no other information.

How do I set a Page Name for a CMS page in Magento Enterprise 1.12.0.2? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not set anywhere by default.  You could set it when you create the block in the layout xml using an action call eg:

```
<action method="setPageName"><name>blah/blahblah/foo.html</name></action>
```

You could set it in a controller by calling the setPageName() method on the block.  Or you could just override the Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga class and add your own custom functionality:

```
public function getPageName()
{
    if (!$this->hasData('page_name')) {
        $this->setPageName(Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->escape($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
     }
    return $this->getData('page_name');
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on the <action> method? For example, if I were to put this in through the Admin->CMS->Page function is this a design XML update or a Layout one? Also, what <reference> would it go into? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, based on Roscius version:

```
public function getPageName()
{
    if (!$this->hasData('page_name')) {
        $this->setPageName(str_replace(Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title_prefix'), '', $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle()));
     }
    return $this->getData('page_name');
}
```